# Slickgrid: show empty groups?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slickgrid

Is there a way I can provide a SlickGrid with a predetermined list of group values that will show up in the grid regardless of whether there are rows in that group? I have a grid that the user can group by a couple of different columns, so I would need to be able to update this when groupBy is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't right now, but I'm working on adding multi-level grouping to it right now, so this would be a good time to voice your suggestions :)

I don't really see how this would fit into the current DataView API.  Do you have any ideas on that?

**UPDATE:**
The new multi-level grouping has been implemented and support for predefined group values has been added in https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/commit/8c840b2e81e858f44b57f4bf351cfb0b5197af66.

Comment: Tin... if mmitchel mean grouping by multiple columns at the same time, then my pull request already does that in the code change I gave you... The grouping example I modified has 3 groups with 1 click of a button, though I might have misunderstood the question, so correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, I'm working on integrating your pull request.  There are some fixes/improvements I had to make, but I'm also trying to add in separate aggregators per group level as well as a more coherent API.

I believe @mmitchell is asking about specifying groups for values that don't exist.  Say, you're grouping by Priority (hi/med/low), but there are no Low-priority values.  How could we specify all possible values so that the Low priority group is shown, albeit empty?

Comment: oh yeah ok I see what you mean, in this case yes the group would never exist and fall instead into a "null" group. There's no predefined groups in your API, unless you want to define the array of groups right from the beginning (instead of dynamically building it), but implementing it this way is a little tricky since you might end up with values that don't fall in any of the groups (exceptions) and you'll have to deal with those too.

Comment: Hence my asking for input on potential ways of addressing this in the API :)

Comment: Hey Tin, thanks for answering. Your example is exactly what I'm asking about. My understanding of the APIs is a bit fuzzy but right now it seems like the simplest way would be to be able to provide an array of fixed group values to the groupBy function, in addition to the existing parameters. So I could provide ['High', 'Medium', 'Low'], and those values would always appear, treated otherwise as normal groups. Rows with group values not in the list could still be grouped as normal, so if there was also a row whose priority was "Top", you would have four groups.